# gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, ubuntu-13.10

I am trying to install Jenkins on Ubuntu 13.10 and I am getting the above mentioned error when i try to run the following command:

```
wget -q -O - http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: notice, that's `-O` option but not `-0` one

Answer (score 143):

This problem might occur if you are behind corporate proxy and corporation uses its own certificate. Just add "--no-check-certificate" in the command.
e.g.
`wget --no-check-certificate -qO - http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key add -`

It works.
If you want to see what is going on, you can use verbose command instead of quiet before adding "--no-check-certificate" option.
e.g. 
`wget -vO - http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key add -`
This will tell you to use "--no-check-certificate" if you are behind proxy.

Comment: I don't know what this does but it seems to have fixed another issue for me for downloading a Microsoft key into GPG

Comment: This should be the answer. This worked for me for AWS EC2

Comment: I did `curl -fsSL --no-check-certificate https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -` but it gave me `command not found` and `gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.` error.

Comment: @Chan Kim: `--no-check-certificate` is a command-line option for `wget`, not `curl`.

Comment: I would caution any who read this answer as this seems very dangerous, considering the question is regarding GPG. Not validating that the certificate ensures that you do not check who actually issued this key, bypassing a very important step, ensuring that the key was given from a trusted server. By doing this you do not know if the server is spoofing the server who you think you are talking to, compromising the validity of the key to be used in GPG.

Maybe you need to refresh your keys? `gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com --refresh-keys`

Answer (score 73):

I got this error in an Ubuntu Docker container. I believe the cause was that the container was missing CA certs. To fix it, I had to run:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install ca-certificates
```

Comment: No idea why this was downvoted but this was my issue, thanks!

Comment: thanks, it solved my issue on ubuntu 16.04 LTS docker container

Comment: I use the systemd-nspawn on Raspbian. The machine is Debian. This solution is also very usefull for me.

Comment: got no idea but this solves my problem when installing mongodb on wsl ubuntu

Answer (score 62):

Managed to resolve it.
separated the command in to two commands and used directly the file name which was downloaded
 example -

```
wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key    add -
```

can be separated into

1. `wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key`
2. `sudo apt-key add jenkins-ci.org.key`

Comment: This worked for me, adding "jenkins-ci.org.key" after -O in the first command.

Comment: When I tried to execute above commands, faced error saying 'no such file or directory named jenkins-ci.org.key' . As a work around I created file with name 'jenkins-ci.org.key' and executed above commands and it worked like charm!! .

Comment: You can pipe them.  Try `| APT_KEY_DONT_WARN_ON_DANGEROUS_USAGE=1 apt-key add -`

Answer (score 25):

> gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.

In this scenario, the message is a cryptic way of telling you that **the download failed**.  Piping these two steps together is nice when it works, but it kind of breaks the error reporting -- especially when you use `wget -q` (or `curl -s`), because these suppress error messages from the download step.

There could be any number of reasons for the download failure.  My case, which wasn't *exactly* listed so far, was that the proxy settings were lost when I called the enclosing script with `sudo`.

Comment: In my case (`https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key`) it was because of a bad cert. Strangely enough, chrome accepts the `https` connection, but `wget` (on Ubuntu 18.04) complains. I assume Chrome and linux are using different certificate chains. The key to understand the problem was to remove the `-q` flag from `wget` as you suggest, and the problem became plain and clear. I had to add `--no-check-certificate` for `wget` to work.

Comment: `curl` also has `--show-error` >When used with -s, --silent, it makes curl show an error message if it fails.

Answer (score 19):

I too got the same error, when I did this behind a proxy. But after I exported the following from a terminal and re-tried the same command, the problem got resolved:

```
export http_proxy="http://username:password@proxy_ip_addr:port/"
export https_proxy="https://username:password@proxy_ip_addr:port/"
```

Comment: How to get proxy_ip_addr and port? Also is username and password means my machine username and password?

Comment: Still i am getting error after exporting above mentioned variables

Answer (score 6):

i got this problem "gpg-no-valid-openpgp-data-found" and solve it with the following first i open browser and paste  https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key
then i download the key in Downloads folder then
cd /Downloads/ then
**sudo apt-key add jenkins-ci.org.key**
if Appear "**OK**" then you success to add the key :)

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue.

The command I used was as follows:

```
wget -qO https://download.jitsi.org/jitsi-key.gpg.key |  apt-key add -
```

I forgot a hyphen between the flags and the URL, which is why wget threw an error.

This is the command that finally worked for me:

```
wget -qO - https://download.jitsi.org/jitsi-key.gpg.key |  apt-key add -
```

Comment: I still get gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found. How am I supposed to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the problem turned out to be that the keyfile was behind a 301 Moved Permanently redirect, which the curl command failed to follow. I fixed it by using `wget` instead:

```
wget URL
sudo apt-key add FILENAME
```

...where FILENAME is the file name that `wget` outputs after it downloads the file.

Update: Alternatively, you can use `curl -L` to make curl follow redirects.

Comment: I faced the similar issue with the curl, as per your update I added -L which worked like a charm for me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

you forgot sudo ... try with sudo and you will get OK

```
sudo wget -q -O - http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

Comment: You do not need super user permissions to `wget` the key, and on the `apt-key add` command the questioner uses `sudo`

Comment: And if it was permission issue, it would say so, not `gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found
`.

Answer (score 2):

Try executing the commands separately.

```
 wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc
```

then

```
sudo apt-key add -
```

Answer (score 1):

By executing the following command, it will save a jenkins-ci.org.key file in the current working directory:

```
curl -O http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key
```

Then use the following command to add the key file:

```
apt-key add jenkins-ci.org.key
```

If the system returns OK, then the key file has been successfully added.

Answer (score 1):

```
export https_proxy=http://user:pswd@host:port
                   ^^^^
```

Use `http` for https_proxy instead of `https`

Comment: replacing https to http worked for me..
Before replace : "wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -" , After replace : "sudo wget -qO- http://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | sudo apt-key add -"

Answer (score 1):

**install gpg** and

1-Import the repository’s GPG key:

```
wget -qO - https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add -
```

2-this is code repository elasticserach in linux for download

```
echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list
```

3-link download elasticsearch

```
  https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch
```

if error "**Job for elasticsearch.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status elasticsearch.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.**"

**solution:**

1-`sudo journalctl -f`

2-`sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch.service`

3-`sudo systemctl start elasticsearch`

Answer (score 1):

I guess the issue is with wrong GPG key. Jenkins changed their GPG key recently (16 April 2020). You might need to import the correct key following the current official directions.

`wget -q -O - https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/jenkins.io.key | sudo apt-key add -`

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1** - Update CA certificates

Update your system's certificate authorities (CA) certificates to ensure they are current and can verify SSL certificates correctly. In Ubuntu, you can do this with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
```

**Solution 2** - Use `wget` instead of `curl`

If updating the CA certificates doesn't resolve the issue, try using wget instead of curl to download the Docker GPG key

```
sudo wget -O /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg
```

**Solution 3** - Check your network and firewall settings

Make sure your internet connection is working correctly, and there are no firewall rules or other network restrictions preventing the secure connection to the "download.docker.com" server. You can try accessing the URL directly in your web browser to check if it's accessible.

**Solution 4** - Verify DNS settings

Ensure that your DNS settings are configured correctly. If your DNS server is not resolving the hostname properly, it can lead to SSL certificate verification issues. You can check your DNS settings by running:

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

**Solution 5** - Disable SSL certificate verification (**not recommended**)

Please note that disabling SSL certificate verification is not recommended from a security standpoint. However, as a temporary workaround for testing purposes, you can use the --insecure option with curl to ignore SSL certificate verification:

```
sudo curl -fsSL --insecure https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
```

Answer (score 0):

`wget` may not be using up to date root certificates. In that case it will output nothing to stdout, causing `apt-key` to throw the error of the description. I could resolve this by upgrading my debian 9.5 image to the latest 9.13

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade -y
```

before running `wget`

Answer (score 0):

There's another, very basic reason that triggers the error message that is the title of this post:

This error message happens if you try to decrypt an unencrypted file.

The message is saying that  gpg did try to read the file to decrypt, but it could not find the info it needed, the info the encrypt process writes there.

So the message can also mean "double-check you gave the correct file to decrypt, it looks like it is not an encrypted file".

Like this:

```
# Encrypt your file
encrypt my_text_file > my_encrypted_file

# ERROR! You try to decrypt the unencrypted file DON'T DO THIS
decrypt my_text_file > decrypted_file
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found. 
gpg: decrypt_message failed: Unknown system error

# You unencrypt the correct (encrypted) file and it works 
decrypt  my_encrypted_file > decrypted_file
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the error **gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.** For my **Ubuntu 20.04**
Firstly:

> sudo apt-get update

then,

> sudo apt-get install ca-certificates

Finally,

> sudo apt install curl

Answer (score 0):

For those facing **gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.** during docker installation due to **curl: (5) Could not resolve proxy:** could clear their list of proxies and try again;

```
env | grep -i proxy  //for listing all proxies
unset <name of the proxy>  // remove all proxies that is shown in the error
```

Example :

```
unset http_proxy
unset HTTPS_PROXY
```

Answer (score -4):

I also got the same error. I've referred to the below mentioned link and ran this commands

[gpg --import fails with no valid OpenPGP data found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18967942/gpg-import-fails-with-no-valid-openpgp-data-found)

```
gpg --import KEYS
sudo apt-get update
```

It worked.

I'm using Ubuntu version 12.04

Comment: this means `gpg --import KEYS` will bypass (work like) `apt-key add KEYS`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I dont understand how to apply this solution.  How does the text "gpg --import KEYS" "sudo apt-get update" relate to the command "wget -q -O - http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key add -"?  what is KEYS? if you dont now need to use wget, how do you get the key?  If I try "# gpg --import KEYS" i get a lot of errors, including "pgp: cant open KEYS: no such file or directory"

Comment: maybe he meant the word KEYS as a placeholder for your key source URL.