# Error: gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found while installing Filezilla

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command, filezilla

Here I am trying to install Filezilla in ubuntu 16.04. The commands which I use are:

1. `sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb apps" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list'`
2. `wget -q -O- http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -`
3. `sudo apt update && sudo apt install filezilla`

But when I try the second command I am getting an error

> gpg: "no valid OpenPGP data found"

Can anyone tell me how to overcome this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not programming-related and therefore off-topic for SE and would be better suited for [Ask Ubuntu](https://www.askubuntu.com) or even [SuperUser](https://www.superuser.com)

Answer (score 1):

Same problem when installing sublime. You can try like below:

```
$ wget -q -O- http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key
$ sudo apt-key add getdeb-archive.key
```

Reference:
[gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338721/gpg-no-valid-openpgp-data-found)