# Running `apt update` raises: "GPG error: cloud-sdk is not signed"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gcloud-cli

While running `sudo apt update` the following Warning, followed by an Error raises:

```
W: GPG error: http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B53DC80D13EDEF05
E: The repository 'http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease' is not signed.
```

Does anybody know how can I solve it?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

This is a known issue.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/known-issues#keyexpired

*Updated 2024:*

apt-key is deprecated, the new way is to store the keys in separate files.

Get the latest key with:

```
curl  https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/google-keyring.gpg
```

and use `[signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/google-keyring.gpg]`  in package definition file in `/etc/apt/sources-list.d/`:

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/google-keyring.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main
```

*Original answer (deprecated)*

Run the following command to obtain the latest key:

```
wget https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg \
    && apt-key add apt-key.gpg
```

or

```
curl -O https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg \
    && apt-key add apt-key.gpg
```

or.. *if you like it simple without extraneous files and are feeling adventurous:*

```
curl -f https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg \
    | sudo apt-key add -
```

Comment: Or if you are not root `curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -`

Comment: I have the same issue in Ubuntu18 and this didn't solve the issue, its still saying 
`W: GPG error: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6A030B21BA07F4FB
E: The repository 'https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.`

any idea whats happening here??

Comment: In case the above fails with `gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338721/gpg-no-valid-openpgp-data-found

Comment: Doing this has no effect on the error message.

Comment: `wget https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg && apt-key add apt-key.gpg`

Something may be changed, which makes `curl` not working.

Comment: wget no longer doesn't work. Neither does curl.

Comment: The [installation instructions](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#deb) include `curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -`. That extra `--keyring` argument seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Or if this is happening in a Docker image build (thanks to @falsePockets for the above comment): `RUN curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -`

Comment: You can always `curl -S https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | gpg -v -` and verify the key is diff/valid, and then run it again with `| sudo apt-key add -` or `| sudo apt-key --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/cloud.google.gpg add -`. You can always use the output of `sudo apt-key list` to then `sudo apt-key export KEYID | sudo gpg --dearmour -o /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google--exp-xx-xx-xxxx.gpg`. In any event, **make sure to update** `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list` with whichever path you chose. `kubernetes.list` can use the same key too, as an FYI!.

Comment: Now responds: `gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.`

Comment: it`s work for me curl -f https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -

Comment: curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -