# cloud sdk not signed

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm trying to install the cloud sdk on my system (ubuntu 20.04), and I run into some problems:

```
W: GPG error: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B53DC80D13EDEF05
E: The repository 'https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease' is not signed.
```

I see that this is a [common problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582490/running-apt-update-raises-gpg-error-cloud-sdk-is-not-signed). I have tried the answer in the linked questions, and when I add the key I get:

```
OK
```

I also tried:

```
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -
```

suggested both in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install) (which should be the best command since my system supports the `--keyring` argument) and in some comments in the linked answer. Also in this case I get:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  2659  100  2659    0     0  13566      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 13566
OK
```

But it still fails when running:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

### UPDATE: command list

List obtained from [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install) under debian/ubuntu:

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates gnupg curl sudo`
3. `echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.asc] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list`
4. from the docs: `curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -`
5. `sudo apt-get update`

For step 4. I tried also the supposedly equivalent from the linked SO question:

`wget https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg && sudo apt-key add apt-key.gpg`

Comment: As you have also shared the official document for [Cloud SDK installation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#ubuntu) , please check if you have followed the steps which are linked specifically to systems which support `--keyring` argument.

Comment: yes. When I run `sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates gnupg curl sudo` I get: `[...] is already the newest version` for all of them.
When I run `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list` I do get the echoed string. Just as a reference, I'm using the _signed by_ version because ubuntu 20.04 [supports it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1391954/what-is-the-signed-by-option-in-deb-command)

Answer (score 2):

I have recreated your issue with the steps you shared and got the exact error message

[image]

Even I tried with the suggestion `wget https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg && sudo apt-key add apt-key.gpg` but still the same issue

[image]

This might be a bug in cloud sdk.I suggest you raise a bug report in the [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) so that it will bring attention to the engineering team and be resolved soon.