# gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found. installing jitsi

Tags: installation, ubuntu-18.04, digital-ocean, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I am trying to install jitsi on digital ocean Ubuntu 18.04.3 (LTS) x64. When i try to command

```
wget -qO -  https://download.jitsi.org/jitsi-key.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then I Got `gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found`

How Can I fixed this?

Comment: This Question is a duplicat of https://stackoverflow.com/a/38039880/6207983

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338721/gpg-no-valid-openpgp-data-found)