# updating git ppa error - no valid OpenPGP data found on Debian

Tags: git, debian, apt

I'm trying to update the git version on a Debian 10 (buster) machine and running into issues with gpg key.

```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
 The most current stable version of Git for Ubuntu.

For release candidates, go to https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/candidate .
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmpfqaimru3/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: /tmp/tmpfqaimru3/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key A1715D88E1DF1F24: public key "Launchpad PPA for Ubuntu Git Maintainers" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

I also tried to manually add key, but still end up with same error after adding the key successfully.

```
> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A1715D88E1DF1F24
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.pwYjc1J0zy/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A1715D88E1DF1F24
gpg: key A1715D88E1DF1F24: public key "Launchpad PPA for Ubuntu Git Maintainers" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
```

And also:

```
> gpg --export  A1715D88E1DF1F24 | sudo apt-key add  -
gpg: WARNING: nothing exported
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've also done update a few times.

```
> sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). https://serverfault.com/ seems a better place. But this has been asked tons of times already, you should be able to find your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21338721/gpg-no-valid-openpgp-data-found) or maybe [here](https://gist.github.com/virgilwashere/17e99763b4f0c210486d5ece2befd5f8).

Comment: Thanks @0stone0, I've already tried both of those things if you see my description above, it still hasn't resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this in a docker container and

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
```

doesn't work there as well. But

```bash
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A1715D88E1DF1F24
sudo gpg --export  A1715D88E1DF1F24 | sudo apt-key add  -
```

works.

**note** that the only difference to your command is, that i am invoking the `gpg --export` command with sudo.

The explanation for this behaviour is, that

```bash
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys A1715D88E1DF1F24
```

imports the key into the keyring of root. So if you invoke the command without sudo gpg cant find the key you've imported.

Answer (score 0):

As in [this issue](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/3474), check if you see expired keys with `sudo apt-key list`

Depending on what you see in  `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, you could infer the URL of the '`gpgkey`' to import.

```
curl -L https://.../git-core/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add -
```

Comment: It says unknown:

```
> sudo apt-key list
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
pub   rsa2048 2022-05-21 [SC]
      A362 B822 F6DE DC65 2817  EA46 B53D C80D 13ED EF05
uid           [ unknown] Rapture Automatic Signing Key (cloud-rapture-signing-key-2022-03-07-08_01_01.pub)
sub   rsa2048 2022-05-21 [E]

pub   rsa1024 2009-01-22 [SC]
      E1DD 2702 88B4 E603 0699  E45F A171 5D88 E1DF 1F24
uid           [ unknown] Launchpad PPA for Ubuntu Git Maintainers

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/debian-archive-bullseye-automatic.gpg
------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: @Ankit So nothing expired, then? Did you see at any point a  `public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY ...`?

Comment: none of the keys in that list have expired.